# Why are all of my threads sleeping using sleep()?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sleep

I saw the following piece of code regarding threading in Linux on the web. But when I run it, all the threads seem to sleep instead of just the main thread. Why? Also, without sleep(5), the statement-"Thread created successfully" runs 3 times instead of 2? Can someone please explain this behavior? Thanks
Compiled using:
gcc -pthread check.c

and my o/p:
First thread processingn
Thread created successfullyn
Second thread processingn
Thread created successfullyn

The first two lines are printed with a lag of 5sec and the next 2 after 5 more sec. Why are the child threads getting slept instead of the main?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
pthread_t tid[2];

void* doSomeThing()

{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    if (pthread_equal(id,tid[0]))
    {
        printf("\n First thread processingn");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Second thread processingn");
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        sleep(5);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread [%s]", strerror(err))
            else

                printf("\n Thread created successfullyn");
        i++;
        // sleep(5);
    }
    pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does `doSomeThing` take `void arg`?

Comment: You might like to read about "*detached*" vs. "*joinable*" state of a thread, to undetstand why you threads do not look as if they ended. For your reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.3.html

Comment: As you wrote it your code does not compile. (should be `void* arg` but you wrote `void arg`)

Comment: BTW, I don't observe the behavior you are describing. I believe the code you compile is not the code you are showing us.

Comment: I agree, I had changed that argument o void* when it gave me an error. The problem is, I'm currently using windows OS, I can't switch to linux for the moment. Can you please tell me the o/p you're getting?

Comment: Please edit your question to give the genuine source code (you need to add four spaces in front of every line!), the compilation command, and the actual output. Also, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Improve the code till there is no warning. Learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Of course you should install Linux on your laptop.

Comment: Concerning the missing output, calling `fflush()` is one way. Much better though is to simply add a newline (`\n`) at the *end* of the line instead of the beginning. The reason is that the default for many implementations is that the output is line-buffered, so writing a newline automatically flushes the output buffer.

Comment: If you had more than one point, I would have downvoted your question: I explained in my reply that you should flush the buffer, and you didn't do it. So what's the point of asking questions if you don't listen to answers?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think all your threads are sleeping? Read some [pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) & [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

It looks like your threads are very quickly terminated. You should have joined them (e.g. before the `sleep`, or somewhere inside `main`) using [pthread_join(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)

```
 for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    void* retval = NULL;
    pthread_join(tid[i], &retval);
    // in your case, since doSomething gives NULL :
    assert (retval == NULL); 
 }
```

or you should have created detached threads, see [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) & example in [pthread_attr_init(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html) & [pthread_attr_setdetachstate(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.3.html) etc....

And you should have coded (since you expect `doSomeThing` to get a `NULL` argument):

```
void* doSomeThing(void* arg) {
   assert (arg == NULL);
```

BTW, please compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

You probably should **call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)** at appropriate places (because [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is often [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer)), e.g. call `fflush(NULL);` at the end of `doSomeThing`

Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and work hard to avoid it.

It is important to do `fflush(NULL);` inside threads from which you expect output (at least before ending them). Your question is not related to `sleep` but to buffering. And `printf` is often buffered, for very valid performance reasons. And you should also take the habit to end `printf` format control string with `\n` (since that is often flushing the buffer). Putting an `\n` only at the beginning of a `printf` format string is a bad habit (it should be at the end).

---

BTW, by correcting the `void* doSomething(void*arg)` line (since with `void arg` as given in the original version of your question the code does not even compile!) I observe the following output at compilation:

```
 % gcc -Wall -g x.c -pthread -o xx
   x.c: In function 'doSomeThing':
   x.c:11:19: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
        unsigned long i = 0;
                      ^
```

then executing with:

```
   % ./xx

   Thread created successfully

   First thread processing

   Thread created successfully

   Second thread processing
```

So the code given in the question does not behave on my computer as explained in the question. Therefore [Harsh S. Kulshrestha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4207519/harsh-s-kulshrestha) should edit his question by giving the *exact* source code, the complete compilation command, and the *exact* output. FWIW, my system is a Linux/Debian/Sid on x86-64, `gcc` is version 4.9.2, `libc` is Debian GLIBC 2.19-15

Comment: I think first parameter to `pthread_join` is `pthreat_t` type, not `pthread_t *`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the answer, but I think that thread tid[1] keeps sleeping because the statement-"Second thread processing" gets printed only  after 5 sec.

Comment: Did you add calls to `fflush`? Without it data might be still buffered and not appear when you want it to...

Comment: Yes I did. Also, when I shift sleep(5) inside the loop just after the statement where threads are invoked, ie, after this:
err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
Both the threads get suspended along with the the main thread.
Do children get suspended if parent is suspended?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, thanks for the continuous help man. I've posted my compiled code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646159/child-threads-sleeping-instead-of-main-thread
I hope you understand my problem now.

Comment: You should not have posted a new question. You should have edited this one. And you should call `fflush`

Comment: Your problem is to understand what buffering means (it is not at all related to `sleep` inside threads!) As I told you should add `fflush(NULL);` at some places in your code.