# Child threads sleeping instead of main thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sleep

This is with respect to the question [Why are all of my threads sleeping using sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643998/why-are-all-of-my-threads-sleeping-using-sleep).

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
pthread_t tid[2];

void* doSomeThing()

{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    if (pthread_equal(id,tid[0]))
    {
        printf("\n First thread processingn");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Second thread processingn");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        sleep(5);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread [%s]", strerror(err))
            else

                printf("\n Thread created successfullyn");
        i++;
        // sleep(5);
    }
    pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
First thread processingn
Thread created successfullyn
Second thread processingn
Thread created successfullyn
```

The first two lines get displayed after 5 sec, and the next two after 5 more sec. Why are the child threads getting slept instead of the main thread? There shouldn't be any lag printing the o/p, isn't it?

Comment: `printf()`ing to `stdout` is (line-)buffered. Use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` instead of `printf(...)`, as `stderr` is not buffered (by default).

Comment: Alternatively, use `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` at the beginning of your program to make `stdout` unbuffered.

Comment: As I told in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28644053/841108) to the original question (same as this one), you should add `fflush(NULL);` at appropriate places in your code, and you should understand what is buffering.